# how to represent owl generic e.g. parametric classes?

Tags: generics, owl, reification

I understand owl doesn't have generic e.g. parametric classes: POTUS(startyear,endyear).   What is the best way to represent this?
is my only alternative using instances and reification rather than classes? my model has to be able to answer who the president is in a given year (and so for a lot of concepts) ideally using DL rather than SPARQL.

```
:Obama a owl:NamedIndividual.
:POTUS a owl:NamedIndividual.

:role01 a owl:NamedIndividual;
    :person :Obama;
    :role :POTUS;   
    :startYear 2009;
    :endYear 2017.
```